# Approximating ground-state energy without using variational principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, harmonic-oscillator, variational-principle

Given the Hamiltonian for one dimension harmonic oscillator: $$H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{\mu\omega}{2}x^2 ,$$ I need to calculate the approximate ground state energy using the following guess for wavefunction:
$$\Psi(x) = A\exp(-\alpha x^2).$$
But this has to be done WITHOUT using the variational principle. Please point me in the right direction.

EDIT: I don't see how substituting $\Psi(x)$ in $H$ is going to help. If this is the correct approach, please walk me through the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to substitute the guess in the time-independent Schrödinger equation.

Comment: But that is not giving me anything useful. All I get is : H Psi = f(x) Psi. Now, f(x) can't be energy right?

Comment: @hhsomething69 Maybe, for the right choice of $\alpha$, you get $f(x)=$constant. Then it *could* be energy, right?

Comment: Your $H$ should have $\omega^2$.

Comment: This procedure will actually give you an *exact* energy eigenvalue, not an approximation.

Comment: @JahanClaes how am I supposed to get that value of $\alpha$ and how is it going to be the ground state energy?

Comment: @hhsomething69 : I gave you a hint, but I am not supposed to do your homework for you.

Comment: @hhsomething69 You'll have to do algebra to find the proper $\alpha$! You can figure out what $f(x)$ is for every $\alpha$, so you just have to figure out what $\alpha$ makes it a constant. The fact that it's a ground state (and not another eigenstate) comes from looking at the form of the wavefunction itself. Try drawing out the wavefunction, and thinking about what the ground state, first excited state, etc, should look like.

Answer (score 0):

The approximate energy is given by

$$
E_a  = \langle \Psi | H | \Psi \rangle
$$

However the above assumes that $\Psi$ is normalized. So first find $A$ such that

$$
\langle \Psi | \Psi \rangle = 1.
$$

You will see that $E_a$ will depend, of course, on $\alpha$. The variational principle would correspond to optimize the energy as a function of $\alpha$.